# Angular paginate not showing second page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a pagination using this [Angular Pagination Directive](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) popular extension but i managed to set almost everything except that when i click on next page it still seems displaying the first one.

**My Controller**

```
.controller('FeaturedController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var featuredArticles = {};

    $scope.featured = featuredArticles;

    selectFeaturedArticles = function (articles) {
        for (x = 0; x < articles.length; x++) {
            if (articles[x].category == 'featured') {
                featuredArticles[x] = articles[x];
            }
        }

        return featuredArticles;
    };
    selectFeaturedArticles(articles);

    //Pagination

    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.pageSize = 3;


    $scope.pageChangeHandler = function (num) {
        console.log('going to page ' + num);
    };

}
```

**My  View**

```
<div class="row featured-row" ng-controller="FeaturedController">
<div dir-paginate="article in featured | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">

    <div class="col-md-4 text-center" >
        <img src="{{ asset('images/1.jpg') }}" alt="image" class="img-circle">
        <h2>@{{ article.title | capitalize }}</h2>
        <p> Featured </p>
        <p> @{{ article.description }}</p>
        <p> @{{ $index }}</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <dir-pagination-controls

            boundary-links="true"

            on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"

            template-url="{{ asset('js/dirPagination.tpl.html') }}">

    </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

I am using Angular with Laravel together.

Comment: you need to call that function which get data from server for next page inside 'pageChangeHandler' function on controller.

Comment: You want to display featured articles in paginated view ?

Comment: Could you give me an example please. I have not understand what you exactly mean. I am new to angular so be patient please. Yes i want to display featured articles in paginated view .

Comment: @NicoOrfi do you want to run pagination on local data inside controller??

Comment: I have the articles variable available, and there are 6 of them in a collection of objects. And i want to paginate them by 3. I have managed to display the first 3 but when i click next i can not see the other ones.